# Searching sequential file loading into array vb.net and searching

Tags: arrays, vb.net, search

I'm using VB.NET 2010 and have been trying to wrap my head around implementing a search feature using a sequential file. Originally I was trying to use a sequential file to read from and search but that has proven to be extremely difficult so I've taken a simple approach using two different arrays with data and try to search through Artist and Album.

The code below takes input from txtSearch.Text which will be for search by artist. I have a duplicate artist "TeeBee" but when I search for that artist I only receive one result instead of two as there are two different albums under the artist "TeeBee".

I thought about adding another loop but it doesn't work. I also thought that the results were getting cut off as there isn't a way to add a return to the results to continue on.

I'm a beginner to programming so please keep that in mind.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    ' Artist array
    Dim strArtist() As String = {"Dillinja", "TeeBee", "Dieselboy", "TeeBee"}
    ' Album array
    Dim strAlbum() As String = {"Untitled", "Scorpion", "Horns", "Blades"}

    Dim strSearchForArtist As String
    Dim intSub As Integer

    ' artist search
    strSearchForArtist = txtSearch.Text

    Do Until intSub = strAlbum.Length OrElse
        strSearchForArtist = strArtist(intSub)
        intSub = intSub + 1
    Loop

    If intSub < strArtist.Length Then
        lstLibrary.Items.Add(strArtist(intSub) & " " & strAlbum(intSub) & vbNewLine)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid", "Bad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Attempt to load text file into array but it doesn't create separate arrays like album, artist genre. - 11-19-14

---

Private Sub btnLoadArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadArray.Click
        Dim filePath As String = "library.txt"

```
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
    sr = IO.File.OpenText(filePath)

    ' look inside file and read every line
    ' this will be how we put the number for
    ' our array below
    Dim TotalLines As Integer = 0

    Dim word As String = ""
    ' need 3 to be dynamic so we get all lines in the file to build the array words(#) 
    ' wanted to use words(,) but that does not work
    Dim words() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' when the peak value is -1 we're at the end of the file
    Do Until sr.Peek = -1
        ' load one at a time
        word = sr.ReadLine()
        ' load word into array
        words(i) = word

        ' output
        lstArtist.Items.Add(words(i))
        ' increment counter
        i += 1
    Loop

    'close the file
    sr.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use a class to represent the couple Artist/Album instead of separate arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of using arrays and handle all the complications I really suggest you to have a more *object oriented approach*

So start defining a class to keep the info for an Album like this

```
Public Class Album
   Public ArtistName as String
   Public AlbumTitle as String
   Public Function ToString() as String
        return ArtistName & " - " & AlbumTitle
   End Function
End Class
```

Now you could remove the array mess using a `List(Of Album)` and asking to each item of this list to render its content via the `ToString` method.

Also an important role here is reserved to the [IEnumerable function Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) that extract from the List(Of Album) all the elements that respects the [Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) required by the Where method.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    ' Here the list is fixed but you can easily build it loading data from a database
    ' or from some other storage medium like a file etc...
    Dim albumList = new List(Of Album) From _
    { 
        new Album With { .ArtistName = "Dillinja",  .AlbumTitle = "Untitled" },
        new Album With { .ArtistName = "TeeBee",  .AlbumTitle = "Scorpion"},
        new Album With { .ArtistName = "Dieselboy",  .AlbumTitle =  "Horns" },
        new Album With { .ArtistName = "TeeBee",  .AlbumTitle = "Blades" }
    }

    ' To help search you could integrate the ToLower expressions in 
    ' Plutonix answer here...
    Dim searchTerm = txtSearch.Text
    Dim searchResult = albumList.Where(Function(x) x.ArtistName = searchTerm)

    lstLibrary.Items.Clear()
    if searchResult.Count > 0 Then
        For Each item in searchResult
            lstLibrary.Items.Add(item.ToString())
        Next
    Else
       MessageBox.Show("Not found")
    End if 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than arrays, a `List(of String)` is easier to manage and provides more efficiency and the kind of functions you probably want.

```
Private Artists As New List(of String)

....
Artists.Addrange({"Dillinja", "TeeBee", "Dieselboy", "TeeBee"})
...
' find a single item:
If Artists.Contains(txtSearch.Text) Then      ' no looping required
   ' a dupe
Else
    ' not a dupe
End If
```

To get all the matching items:

```
Dim find = Artists.Where(Function(s) _ 
    s.ToLowerInvariant = txtSearch.Text.ToLowerInvariant).ToList
```

The resulting `find` will also be a List(of String) containing the matching item.  This time it is case insensitive.  To get the *count* of dupes:

```
Dim finds = Artists.LongCount(Function(n) n.ToLowerInvariant =  _   
       txtSearch.Text.ToLowerInvariant.ToLowerInvariant)
```

I dont know how much value either can be.  Neither `2` nor a List of "Teebee", "TeeBee" is very useful or interesting.  More typically, you want the return to be the entire object (like an album) associated with the search term.  This requires a Class which glues Arist, Album, Genere, Tracks etc together though (see Steve's answer for a start on this part).

As for the whole file part, the list(s) can be easily serialized allowing an entire list to be saved or reloaded from disk in 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: I believe part of the problem I'm experiencing is that I'm over thinking the problem and the book I have for learning is rather stale and lacks decent examples and clear explanation as to what's going on. I have managed to re-visit my original idea of making an array from a text file that has multiple items on each row. Essentially what I had though I could do was parse each item but the book hasn't gone over comma delimited files, or searching for spaces that separate each entry on the row like, artist name   album title    genre and then on to the next line.